# Sharpdevelop modify local variable

Tags: debugging, variables, local, sharpdevelop

How does one modify the value of a local variable when debugging/stepping through the code?
Its easy enough with visual studio but I cannot seem to find out how to do the same thing in sharpdevelop 4.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For types such as integers and booleans you can change the value in the Local variables window (View | Debug | Local variables). You can click into the value column and change the variable's value.

[image: Editing an integer local variable in the Local variables window]

For strings and reference types editing their values is not supported in the Local variables window. Instead you can use the Console window (View | Debug | Console). You can then change the variable's value by writing an assign statement and pressing the return key.

[image: Assigning a new string to a string variable in the Console window]